# Buscar un elemento por nombre a través de query string (usando .net core y postman)

Tags: c#, asp.net

necesito buscar un elemento (una pelicula) por el titulo, y que sea por query string, necesito que quede algo asi: https://localhost:44388/api/Movies?title=titulo.
este es el codigo que estuve probando sin exito:

```
[HttpGet("title")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Movie>> GetMoviebyTitle(string title){
IQueryable<Movie> query = _context.Movie;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            {
                query = query.Where(n => n.Title.StartsWith(title));
            }

            return query.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Necesito hacer solo el backend por lo que estoy usando postman para probar (sin vistas razor ni nada por lo que no puedo hacer un return view)
Agradezco cualquier ayuda, creo que estoy encarando mal el problema la verdad, ya que no estoy familiarizado con los query string.

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando la consulta deberia funcionar bien. Tambien tu metodo deberia marcarte que tenes async pero ningun await, lo cual estas corriendolo de forma sincronica. Fijate como te agregue el await y con el firstOrDefaultAsync, te ejecuta la consulta, envolviendola entre `()` tambien te pedira con ese metodo agregar la libreria EntityFramework.Core

Y como Consejo, no trabajes logica y consultas en el controlador.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

[HttpGet("title")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Movie>> GetMoviebyTitle(string title)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
   {
     return null;
   }
   
   IQueryable<Movie> query = await (_context.Movie.Where(n => n.Title.StartsWith(title)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
   
   return query;
}
```